# How to validate textform field for special characters when it can be null in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to validate textformfield for special characters but it can also be null, **For Example:** Middle name: Not every one has middle name so it can be null but for those who have middle name it has to be alphabets not special characters. How do i do it?

Comment: show us your attempts. what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
final RegExp _alphabetRegex = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$');

TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Middle name'),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return null; // Return null if the value is empty or null
    } else if (!_alphabetRegex.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Middle name can only contain alphabets'; // Return an error message if the value contains special characters
    }
    return null; // Return null if the value is valid
  },
);
```